# Finding Jordan canonical form of a $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1&-2&1&0 \\ 1&-2&1&0 \\ 1&-2&1&0 \\ 1&-1&0&0
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find the Jordan canonical form and the minimal polynomial. Now I sense that their is a shortcut (due to the triple repeated rows) but I cannot quite work out what it is?

I know that it has an eigenvalue 0 of multiplicity 4, with the minimal polynomial of $x^2$

Also, I got an eigenvecctor to be $(1,1,1,0)$

Comment: Have you found the characteristic polynomial at least?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda^4$

Comment: This is due in tomorrow! Ha.

Comment: @AlecTeal: Is this cheating on some sort of assignment or exam as two questions have been posted today? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti quite a few of this guy's questions are actually from the sheet, it's a for-credit assignment, I'm stuck on one of the questions so I hope I don't shoot myself in the foot by doing this: http://alec-teal.co.uk/task/task.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti all of his questions are from past for-credit sections. I am not against the practice of asking for help, it's annoyed me though that none of the extra-section's questions, or practice are here, and it is the day before. I really hate that.

Comment: @AlecTeal: Does your instructor have a policy of asking for help?

Comment: @Amzoti our tutors and supervisors do, supervisors are not allowed to give answers (in any form) until after the hand-in time. This is annoyingly strict, tutors have an unofficial agreement it seems to only provide hints. I enjoy this practice.

Answer (score 3):

Hints (fill in the details):

The characteristic polynomial is given by:

$$|A-\lambda I| = 0 \rightarrow \lambda^4 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_{1,2,3,4} = 0$$

Since we have an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $4$ and it is zero, we can find the null space of the matrix $A$ which has rank $2$. Thus, two eigenvectors are:

- $v_1 = (0,0,0,1)$
- $v_2 = (1,1,1,0)$

Now, we need two generalized eigenvectors and can find those by solving $[A - \lambda I]v_3 = v_1$, which has a RREF of:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1& 0& -1& 0& 2\\
      0&   1&  -1&  0 & 1\\
      0&  0& 0&  0& 0 \\
   0&  0& 0&  0& 0 
    \end{array}\right]$$

This leads to an eigenvector of $v_3 = (2,1,0,0)$.

We can repeat this for a fourth eigenvector as $[A - \lambda I]v_4 = v_2$, which has a RREF of:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1\\
      0&   1&  -1&  0 & 1\\
      0&  0& 0&  0& 0 \\
   0&  0& 0&  0& 0 
    \end{array}\right]$$

This leads to an eigenvector of $v_4 = (-1, -1,0,0)$.

Now, we know $A$ and $P$ and can find the Jordan block as $J = P^{-1} \cdot A \cdot P$.

Of course we could just figure out the Jordan block from the information above and there are obviously many ways to approach these problems.

**Spoiler**

> The Jordan Normal Form is $J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Deserves a TU! +1